# My UITableViewCell is reusing a previous cells UIImage

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UITable that reuses cells. Each cell has an image dependant on a condition. The correct images are always used however when cells are reused the old image is displayed behind the new one. I have tried to remove the uiimageview before adding a new subview however it has no effect.

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpTableIden = @"simpTableIden";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpTableIden];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpTableIden];

    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.achievements objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:row]] objectForKey:@"name"];

    CGRect picFrame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-cell.frame.size.height, 0,   cell.frame.size.height, cell.frame.size.height);

    UIImage *greyDot = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyDot.png"];
    UIImage *whiteDot = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteDot.png"];
    UIImageView *achievImg = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    achievImg.frame=picFrame;

    if ([[[self.achievements objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:row]] objectForKey:@"achieved"] boolValue]) {

        achievImg.image = whiteDot;
    }
    else {
       achievImg.image = greyDot;
    }

    [achievImg removeFromSuperview];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:achievImg];

    return cell;
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: after scrolling you are getting this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is each time `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called you create a new imageview.
I corrected your code as follows:

Here we create an imageView once for each new new cell and replace it's image every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *simpTableIden = @"simpTableIden";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpTableIden];
  UIImageView *achievImg = nil;
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpTableIden];
    //New Cell ... Create Image view
    achievImg = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    achievImg.tag = 10;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:achievImg];

  }
  else{
    //Old cell...get previously createdd imageview
    achievImg = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
  }
  NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

  cell.textLabel.text = [[self.achievements objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:row]] objectForKey:@"name"];

  CGRect picFrame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-cell.frame.size.height, 0, cell.frame.size.height, cell.frame.size.height);

  UIImage *greyDot = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyDot.png"];
  UIImage *whiteDot = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteDot.png"];


  tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

  achievImg.frame=picFrame;

  if ([[[self.achievements objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:row]] objectForKey:@"achieved"] boolValue]) {

    achievImg.image = whiteDot;
  }
  else {
    achievImg.image = greyDot;
  }

  //You don't need this because it doesn't have a superview in the first place..it's new
  //[achievImg removeFromSuperview];

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I did try something similar without success. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Apple [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) are a great read as well when it comes to understanding how tableViewCells work and how to customize them

Answer (score 0):

You are always adding the imageView to the contentView of the cell. If the cell is reused that will lead to multiple imageViews in cell.

You can give a tag to the imageView. Always check if there is a view will same tag in the contentView of cell. If not add the imageView.

```
UIImageView *achievImg = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:55];
if(!achievImg){
    achievImg = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    achievImg.tag = 55;
    [cell.contentView addSubView:achievImg];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *simpTableIden = @"simpTableIden";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpTableIden];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpTableIden];



        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

        cell.textLabel.text = [[self.achievements objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:row]] objectForKey:@"name"];

        CGRect picFrame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-cell.frame.size.height, 0,   cell.frame.size.height, cell.frame.size.height);

        UIImage *greyDot = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyDot.png"];
        UIImage *whiteDot = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteDot.png"];
        UIImageView *achievImg = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

        tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        achievImg.frame=picFrame;

        if ([[[self.achievements objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:row]] objectForKey:@"achieved"] boolValue]) {

            achievImg.image = whiteDot;
        }
        else {
           achievImg.image = greyDot;
        }

        [achievImg removeFromSuperview];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:achievImg];
       }
        return cell;
     }
```